# Problem with the code of GLCD128x64

Tags: c, 8051, glcd

```
#include <reg51.h> 
#include <intrins.h>
#define dport P2 

//This code is driver for graphics lcd which is 128x64 

sbit rs = P3^0 ; 
sbit rw = P3^1 ; 
sbit en = P3^2 ; 
sbit cs1 = P3^3 ; 
sbit cs2 = P3^4 ; 

unsigned char c,z=0;
unsigned char ar0[]={124,126,19,19,126,124,0,0};    //A,8x8
unsigned char ar1[]={65,127,127,73,127,54,0,0};     //B,8x8
unsigned char ar2[]={28,62,99,65,65,99,34,0};       //C,8x8
unsigned char ar3[]={65,127,127,65,99,62,28,0};     //D,8x8
unsigned char ar4[]={65,127,127,73,93,65,99,0,};    //E,8x8
unsigned char ar5[]={ 65,127,127,73,29,1,3,0};      //F,8x8
unsigned char ar6[]={ 28,62,99,65,81,115,114,0};    //G,8x8
unsigned char ar7[]={127,127,8,8,127,127,0,0};      //H,8x8

unsigned char ar00[]={126,17,17,17,126};        //A,5x7
unsigned char ar11[]={127,73,73,73,54};             //B,5x7
unsigned char ar22[]={62,65,65,65,34};          //C,5x7
unsigned char ar33[]={127,65,65,34,28};         //D,5x7
unsigned char ar44[]={127,73,73,73,65};         //E,5x7
unsigned char ar55[]={127,9,9,1,1};         //F,5x7
unsigned char ar66[]={62,65,65,81,50};          //G,5x7
unsigned char ar77[]={127,8,8,8,127};           //H,5x7

void ctrloff()
{
rs = 0 ;
rw = 0 ;
en = 0 ;
cs1 = 0 ; 
cs2 = 0 ;
}

void displayon()
{
ctrloff() ;
dport = 0x3F ;  // switching on the display command 
cs1 = 1 ;
cs2 = 1 ;
rw = 0 ;
rs = 0 ;
en = 1 ;
_nop_();
en = 0 ;
}
void delay()
{
int i ;
for( i = 0 ; i < 12750 ; i++ ) ;
}
void setcolumn( unsigned char y )
{
if( y < 64 )    
{
    ctrloff() ;
    c = y ;
    dport = 0x40|(y&63) ; // the command is b01(six bits for the column select)
    cs1 = 1 ; cs2 = 0 ;
    rs = 0 ; rw = 0 ;
    en = 1 ;
    _nop_() ;
    en = 0 ;
}
else
{
    ctrloff() ; 
    c = y ;
    dport = 0x40|(y-64) ;
    cs1 = 0 ; cs2 = 1 ;
    rs = 0 ; rw = 0 ;
    en = 1 ;
    _nop_() ;
    en = 0 ;
}
}

void setpage( unsigned char x )  // function for setting the page 
{
ctrloff() ;
dport = 0xb8 | x ;  // the command is b10111011 for setting the fourth page , the last three bits select the page 
cs1 = 0; cs2 = 0 ;
rs = 0 ; rw = 0 ;
en = 1 ;
_nop_() ;
en = 0 ; 
}

void lcddata(unsigned char* value , unsigned char limit ) // function for setting the  data from a particular position 
{
unsigned char i ;
for( i = 0 ; i < limit ; i++ )
{
        if( c<64 ) 
        {
            setcolumn(c)
            dport = value[i] ;
            cs1 = 0 ; cs2 = 0 ;
            rs = 1 ;
            rw = 0 ;
            en = 1 ;
            _nop_();
            en = 0 ;  
        }
        else 
        {
            setcolumn(c);
            dport = value[i] ;
            cs2 = 0 ; cs1 = 1 ; 
            rs = 1 ;
            rw = 0 ;
            en = 1;
            _nop_() ;
            en = 0 ;
            c++ ;
        }
    if(c > 127 )
    return ;
}
}

void clrlcd()
{
unsigned char i,j ;
for( i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++ )
{
    setpage(i) ;
    setcolumn(0);
    for( j = 0 ; j < 128 ; j++ )
        lcddata(&z,1) ;
}
 }

void main()
  { 
     clrlcd();
     while(1)
     {
       displayon(); 
       setpage(0);
       setcolumn(0);
       lcddata(&ar0,8);
       delay() ; 

    setpage(1);
    setcolumn(0);
    lcddata(&ar1,8);
    delay() ; 

    setpage(2);
    setcolumn(0);
    lcddata(&ar2,8);
    delay() ; 

    setpage(3);
    setcolumn(0);
    lcddata(&ar3,8);
    delay() ; 

    setpage(4);
    setcolumn(0);
    lcddata(&ar4,8);
    delay() ; 

    setpage(5);
    setcolumn(0);
    lcddata(&ar5,8);
    delay() ; 

    setpage(6);
    setcolumn(0);
    lcddata(&ar6,8);
    delay() ; 

    setpage(7);
    setcolumn(0);
    lcddata(&ar7,8);
    delay() ; 

    setpage(0);
    setcolumn(64);
    lcddata(&ar00,5);
    delay() ; 

    setpage(1);
    setcolumn(64);
    lcddata(&ar11,5);
    delay() ; 

    setpage(2);
    setcolumn(64);
    lcddata(&ar22,5); 
    delay() ; 

    setpage(3);
    setcolumn(64);
    lcddata(&ar33,5);
    delay() ; 

    setpage(4);
    setcolumn(64);
    lcddata(&ar44,5);
    delay() ; 

    setpage(5);
    setcolumn(64);
    lcddata(&ar55,5);
    delay() ; 

    setpage(6);
    setcolumn(64);
    lcddata(&ar66,5);
    delay() ; 

    setpage(7);
    setcolumn(64);
    lcddata(&ar77,5);
    delay() ; 
} 
 }
```

I am having problem with this code as this is not running when i am trying to run it on proteus with a 128x64 glcd , i think the problem is with setpage function because when i try to access other page i cant . I tried different things with the setpage code but still it is not working . I have commented some sections where i am suspicious that the code might be wrong !!

Comment: I am not able to upload the image because i dont have enough rep but i will tell the problem , the chararcter are being printed at page 0 only , while i am expecting them to print on different pages

Comment: I am quite sure that this question is not a good fit for this site where questions are meant to focus directly to electronics design.

Comment: Can you reduce your code to the smallest chunk that still has the problem?

Comment: @Scott Seidman Yes the setpage function is having the problem